# Laravel's Helpers doesn't works correctly in some contexts/classes

Tags: php, laravel-5, helper

I have a question about use of Laravel's helpers (route helper in my case).

When calling a helper in controllers, it works fine. For example:

```
class PollController extends Controller {

    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $route = route('polls.show'); 
        // returns 'http://application.app/polls/show'
        $data = [
            'user_token' => $request->get('token')
        ];

        return view('polls.form')->with($data);
    }

    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

But, when calling the same helper in artisan tinker or in a command class. For example:

```
class Inspire extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'inspire';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Display an inspiring quote';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $route = route('polls.show'); // **returns 'http://localhost/polls/show'**
        $this->comment(PHP_EOL.Inspiring::quote().PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

It (second case) is not good for me. I tried to solve this by using constants for save the correct value and then use it on command class, but  I had the same problem.

I wish solve this problem and I wish know why the behavior is different in these cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not good for me"? What happens?

Comment: I needed the full path equals to first case. Anyways, it's already solved :) thanks very much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `route()` helper (as well as `url()` and a few bits of Laravel functionality) uses the domain name from the current HTTP request. Since Artisan commands don't *have* a HTTP request, Laravel falls back to the `app.url` configuration setting. Change it (or, by default, your .env `APP_URL` setting) from the default `http://localhost` to your site's URL.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The problem is solved!. I forgot the environment config.
Now I have a new doubt ... What kind of functionalities uses the domain from the current request? Can you send me a link or documentation pls ? 

Thanks for help again !!

Comment: @Jeromy Anything that generates a full URL relies on it. Anything that does so will fall back on this setting, so setting it should cover everything.